# Parameter Value in main report is not passed to a parameter in the subreport

Tags: crystal-reports

I need your assistant in passing a value of a parameter in the main report to the subreport. I defined a parameter in the main report which is called {?ReportNumber} and its type is Number and it is static.

In the Select Expert of the Main Report I added the below code:

```
{engine.reportnumber}={?ReportNumber}
```

This will take the value of the reportnumber from the table and it will assign it to the parameter. Each time I ran the report, the value will be different based on the retrieved data.

In the Subreport, I created again a parameter with the same name {?ReportNumber} and its type is Number and it is static.

I have added a subreport link which is {?ReportNumber} parameter and below I selected to match the {?ReportNumber} parameter which is in the subreport.

However my issue is that when I ran the report, the report is prompting me to enter the parameter of the subreport, even though I have added and assigned a value to it as I have explained in the above steps.

I am using Crystal Reports 2011

Even tried to use shared variable in the main report:

```
shared numbervar report_number := {engine.rptno}; 

report_number;
```

In the sub report, I create a formula ("Shared_report_number") and I placed it in the report header. It has the code:

```
shared numbervar report_number; 

report_number;
```

I clicked on Select Expert and then I chose the field {engine.rptno} is equal to {@Shared_report_number}, it produces an error that : the formula cannot be used because it must be evaluated later

Kindly assist me in passing the value of the parameter from the main report to the subreport.

Comment: Im sub report also give the parameter in select expert and then run the report

Comment: I tried it but it is still showing the prompt

Comment: Are you sure you have selected {?ReportNumber} or {?pm ReportNumber}

Comment: {?pm ReportNumber} will not work because the application is generating an error and it is a 3rd party application. So, I need to try a different way .... I tried to match the same in the subreport {engine.reportnumber} = {?ReportNumber}, but it prompts me

Comment: I tried to match the {?ReportNumber} from the main report using {?pm-ReportNumber} with the field rptno in the subreport, but unfortunately the application produced an error that I can't use the {?pm-ReportNumber}. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Its a typical behaviour..... but I have one solution not sure whether it will work or not..... since you need the parameter in select expert of the sub report....in main report create a formula and create a shared variable as 'numbervar array store' and add store the paramete value in that varable... now use that shared variable in sub report record selection formula as.. shared numbervar array store;   report number=store and delete the paraneter in sub report and link sub report by someother filed. Niw you have only one parameter in entire report. If this works I will post as answer.

Comment: It didn't work. It shows an error that the formula cannot be used because it must be evaluated later

Comment: It is just an idea also I didn't try the solution..if you can post what you have written in formula I can try to help you

Comment: I have modified the contents of the topic at the end, you can have a look at my code at the top

Comment: A small correction I have advised you to use the {?ReportNumber} in the shared variable of the main report.. and use that value in subreport formula... Try and let me know?.. If this is not working `(I am not sure about this approach)` pass the formula to the sub report from main report through links and use the linked formula directly in `select expert` of the main report.

Comment: I tried but It is not wotking

Comment: Is the error same? or any new one?

Comment: See my approach is sample since your parameter linking is not possible I am suggesting you to take the main report data from paramter in to some formula shared variable and pass the value into record selection expert of the sub report so that main report record selection and sub report record selection will be same.... I am confused why you are unable to achieve this..

Comment: I can't use any parameters ... it keeps showing an error "Cannot find parameter field Report_Number in subreport ABCD.rpt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prompting shows that your parameter is not link properly.

When you link the parameter. In left side, main report parameter show 
1. is of sp parameter 
2. is of custom report parameter

While you linking, note that you custom report with report name is joined.

Please check this below link, in UI potion of third image , right-bottom side you have to choose sub-report parameter. So check and then link.

http://blog.niklasottosson.com/?p=1137

In your case, I think your main report parameter is link with itself. not with subreport parameter.

Check this link carefully while mapping.

Comment: I tried the exact steps, however it showed me an error in the application that it can't link with the parameter name

Comment: Should I assign again the {?ReportNumer} = {?ReportNumer} in the Subreport? Will it serve the purpose of assigning?

Comment: I tried to match the {?ReportNumber} from the main report using {?pm-ReportNumber} with the field rptno in the subreport, but unfortunately the application produced an error that I can't use the {?pm-ReportNumber}. Is there any work around for this?